# How to retrieve names of all private MSMQ queues - efficiently?

Tags: powershell, .net, wmi, msmq, com

How can I retrieve the **names** of all of the private MSMQ queues on the local machine, without using `System.Messaging.MessageQueue.GetPrivateQueuesByMachine(".")`? I'm using PowerShell so any solution using COM, WMI, or .NET is acceptable, although the latter is preferable.

Note that [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329038/msmq-get-all-private-queues) has a solution that returns all of the queue objects. I don't want the objects (it's too slow and a little flakey when there are *lots* of queues), I just want their names.

Answer (score 2):

With Windows Server 2012 R2 you have the [Message Queueing (MSMQ)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn391735(v=wps.630).aspx) Cmdlets installed, use the Cmdlet [Get-MsmqQueue](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh405018(v=vs.85).aspx) to get name and count.

```
Get-MsmqQueue | Select QueueName, MessageCount
```

Without Message Queueing (MSMQ) you can use [Get-WmiObject](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849824.aspx)

```
gwmi -class Win32_PerfRawData_MSMQ_MSMQQueue | Select Name
```

Or over **powershell remoting**:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $sessions -ScriptBlock { Get-MsmqQueue | Select QueueName, MessageCount }
```

or

```
$dataRaw = Invoke-Command -Session $sessions -ScriptBlock { gwmi -class Win32_PerfRawData_MSMQ_MSMQQueue } 
$data | Sort-Object -Property PSComputerName,Name  | 
Format-Table  DisplayName, MessagesInQueue, PSComputerName
```

Comment: Note that this is based on message counts, and as a result empty queues will not show up in this query...

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ I changed it to `Get-MsmqQueue`, so you get all queues.

Answer (score 1):

There is a generic cmdlet command available in powershell [Get-MsmqQueue](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh405018(v=vs.85).aspx), to accomplish the task in powershell: `Get-MsmqQueue –QueueType Private | select QueueName`

This will return names of the private queues in string array. Please be aware the type returned by get-msmqqueue cmdlet is Microsoft.Msmq.PowerShell.Commands.MessageQueue, not System.Messaging.MessageQueue, and seems these two types cannot be converted to each other.

Comment: Can you provide any other details about these commands?

Comment: updated with more details, any specific area you looking for?

Comment: Nothing in particular, just not a single line of code, without any context or explanation.

Answer (score -1):

In Powershell everything is an object.  You can choose to list certain properties by using the select command which effectively discards the objects.

Comment: Thanks, @uSlackr. I'm trying to avoid instantiating all the objects if I can help it, because it's very slow. Ideally, I want to instantiate only those queues that have a name matching a certain pattern. Since there is no API for that (that I'm aware of) I want to get the list of names, filter that, then retrieve each queue individually.

Comment: `Select-Object` does not discard the object, it just limits the visible properties.